# Duda con DatagridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, aplicación-escritorio

estoy poblando un DataGridView con datos de SqlServer. Cuando inicio el compilador, todo funciona bien, pero la idea es que pueda filtrar ese DataGrid con un TextBox.

He ahí el problema, al presionar cualquier tecla dentro del textbox el datagridview no muestra ningún valor.

Aquí cargo el datagrid:

```
private void Inicio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
            llenaTitulo();
        }
```

Este es el método para poblarlo:

```
public void llenaTitulo() {
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection();
            conexion.ConnectionString = "acá esta la conexion a mi bd";
            conexion.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT titulo FROM Cuotas", conexion);
            da.Fill(ds, "Cuotas");
            conexion.Close();
            dtgTitulo.DataSource = ds;
            dtgTitulo.DataMember = "Cuotas";
        }
```

Este es el método para filtrarlo:

```
private void filtrarTitulo(string valor){
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection();
        conexion.ConnectionString = "acá esta la conexion a mi bd";
        conexion.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT titulo FROM Cuotas where titulo in (" + valor + ")", conexion);
        da.Fill(ds, "Cuotas");
        conexion.Close();
        dtgTitulo.DataSource = ds;
        dtgTitulo.DataMember = "Cuotas";
    }
```

Y esta la configuración del textbox:

```
private void TxtTitulo_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e){
            filtrarTitulo(txtTitulo.Text.ToString().Trim());
        }
```

El problema, insisto, es que cuando pongo algún valor dentro del textbox el datagridview se queda vacío

Comment: Te recomiendo cambiar el user y el password de tu BD primero de todo, ya que lo has publicad en tu pregunta.

Comment: No sera por que tienes un IN en vez de un LIKE entiendo que quieres filtrar por lo que se ponga con un IN tendria que ser el nombre exacto que tiene

Comment: Y por ejemplo que estas poniendo como titulo, y si tiras el mismo query en la db trae algo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás usando el `IN` en tu consulta, cuando deberías usar `LIKE` para hacer consultas de texto, a parte de poner los `%` para que lo busque en cualquier sitio del título, si es lo que requieres, y poner el texto entre comillas simples `(')`.

Te pongo un ejemplo de como deberías tenerlo:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT titulo FROM Cuotas where titulo LIKE ('%" + valor + "%')", conexion);
```

También te recomiendo no usar esta forma de hacer las consultas SQL para evitar el SQLInjection, deberías pasar por parámetros los valores que deseas añadir a la consulta, de la siguiente forma:

```
string sSQL = "SELECT titulo FROM Cuotas where titulo LIKE '%' + @valor + '%'";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sSQL , conexion);
command.Parameters.Add("@valor", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = valor;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienes razón. Me ha servido

Comment: Una duda, necesito que la consulta no lleve el '%'. Es decir, necesito que sea así: `select titulo from cuotas where titulo like '293%'`
Pero, sucede que si dejo la consulta así : `string sSQL = "SELECT titulo FROM Cuotas where titulo LIKE ' + @valor + %'";`  
vuelve a suceder que no aparece ningún valor

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Tienes que ponerlo entonces así: `string sSQL = "SELECT titulo FROM Cuotas where titulo LIKE @valor + '%'";`

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido bastante. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Tu codigo deberia usar siempre parametros junto al `LIKE` algo como esto

```
private void filtrarTitulo(string valor)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string connstring = "acá esta la conexion a mi bd";
    using(SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {
        conexion.Open();
        string query = "SELECT titulo FROM Cuotas where titulo LIKE '%' + @titulo + '%'";
        SqlCamand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titulo", valor);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(, conexion);
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    dtgTitulo.DataSource = dt;
}
```

No se unen los valores en un string

Comment: Vale, ha sido un golazo. Gracias por la ayuda